# Appending a newline character to a string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a simplest solution to append a newline character to a string.

Although the following code works, I would like to know if it's possible to make the code simpler. (The argument should be `const char*` and not `std::string`)

**My Code :**

```
static void sysGui(const char *s)
{
    char buf[1000];
    std::strcpy(buf, s);
    std::size_t size = std::strlen(s);
    buf[size] = '\n';
    buf[size + 1] = '\0';
    sys_gui(buf);
}
```

Comment: what does sys_gui do?

Comment: @ratchetfreak it sends the string to Tk widgets. It takes `char*` as an argument.

Comment: What do you do is the string is longer than 999 characters? You should allocate the exact needed size not just 1000.

Comment: @MrSmith42 The string will always be less than 1000.

Comment: @TobySpeight I just edited that Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're really certain of the necessary conditions for this to actually work, a somewhat cleaner way to do the job would be to use `sprintf`:

```
static void sysGui(const char *s)
{
    char buf[1000];
    sprintf(buf, "%s\n", s);
    sys_gui(buf);
}
```

You could use a `std::ostringstream` instead, but `sprintf` seems more in keeping with the fact that the rest of the code is essentially C anyway (regardless of how it's tagged).

Comment: This is a cleaner and simpler solution indeed. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd probably still recommend a healthy defensiveness, even if "really certain", by using e.g. `std::snprintf()` at very little extra cost.